# Fire SelectedIndexChanged event on a listbox, when operating with keyboard, only when user presses Enter

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, keyboard

I have a listbox that I populate from my codebehind.  I have a handler for the SelectedIndexChanged event.  When I use the mouse, everything works fine.  It is just a plain, standard listbox, no mysteries.

But when I try to use the keyboard, as soon as I arrow down even once, the SelectedIndexChanged event gets fired, because, of course, the selection is changing.  The list does not wait for me to actively select an item by pressing Enter.  So if I want to select the fifth item, the event gets fired five times, once for each selection.

**Question:**  Is there any way to have a listbox select items only on Enter when operating it with the keyboard?  Or is there a different control I should be using to let the user select an item from a list?

Seems like this would be so necessary for accessibility that someone should have a solution.  Here is my aspx code for the listbox.

```
<asp:ListBox id="OwnersList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" class="dropdown-list StopClickPropagation" onblur='$(".dropdown-list").hide();' on OnSelectedIndexChanged="OwnerSelectionChanged">
</asp:ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, listbox or any other asp.net control can meet your requirement without additional Javascript code. In order to fulfill your requirement, you need to hook up onkeypress and onclick events on client side, and postback through __doPostBack method.

Comment: I should have thought of this.  I will try it and get back to you.